The model works fine in colab environment with TensorFlow 2.17.0
Local environment tensorflow version also 2.17 but when try to load this model locally it returns below error.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\keras\src\ops\operation.py:208, in Operation.from_config(cls, config)
    207 try:
--> 208     return cls(**config)
    209 except Exception as e:

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\keras\src\layers\attention\multi_head_attention.py:115, in MultiHeadAttention.__init__(self, num_heads, key_dim, value_dim, dropout, use_bias, output_shape, attention_axes, kernel_initializer, bias_initializer, kernel_regularizer, bias_regularizer, activity_regularizer, kernel_constraint, bias_constraint, **kwargs)
     97 def __init__(
     98     self,
     99     num_heads,
   (...)
    113     **kwargs,
    114 ):
--> 115     super().__init__(**kwargs)
    116     self.supports_masking = True

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\keras\src\layers\layer.py:264, in Layer.__init__(self, activity_regularizer, trainable, dtype, autocast, name, **kwargs)
    263 if kwargs:
--> 264     raise ValueError(
    265         "Unrecognized keyword arguments "
    266         f"passed to {self.__class__.__name__}: {kwargs}"
    267     )
    269 self.built = False
...
    213     )

TypeError: Error when deserializing class 'MultiHeadAttention' using config={'name': 'multi_head_attention', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'num_heads': 4, 'key_dim': 256, 'value_dim': 256, 'dropout': 0.1, 'use_bias': True, 'output_shape': None, 'attention_axes': [1], 'kernel_initializer': {'module': 'keras.initializers', 'class_name': 'GlorotUniform', 'config': {'seed': None}, 'registered_name': None}, 'bias_initializer': {'module': 'keras.initializers', 'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}, 'registered_name': None}, 'kernel_regularizer': None, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'activity_regularizer': None, 'kernel_constraint': None, 'bias_constraint': None, 'query_shape': [None, 55, 256], 'key_shape': [None, 55, 256], 'value_shape': [None, 55, 256]}.

Exception encountered: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to MultiHeadAttention: {'query_shape': [None, 55, 256], 'key_shape': [None, 55, 256], 'value_shape': [None, 55, 256]}

This is the code of my model.
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Embedding, MultiHeadAttention, LayerNormalization, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

def transformer_encoder(inputs, head_size, num_heads, ff_dim, dropout=0):
    # Normalization and Attention
    x = LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(inputs)
    x = MultiHeadAttention(key_dim=head_size, num_heads=num_heads, dropout=dropout)(x, x)
    x = Dropout(dropout)(x)
    res = x + inputs

    # Feed Forward Part
    x = LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(res)
    x = Dense(ff_dim, activation="relu")(x)
    x = Dropout(dropout)(x)
    x = Dense(inputs.shape[-1])(x)
    return x + res

def build_transformer_model(input_shape, english_vocab_size, sinhala_vocab_size, head_size=256, num_heads=4, ff_dim=512, num_layers=4, dropout=0.1):
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = Embedding(english_vocab_size, head_size)(inputs)

    for _ in range(num_layers):
        x = transformer_encoder(x, head_size, num_heads, ff_dim, dropout)

    outputs = Dense(sinhala_vocab_size, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model

# Build the model
input_shape = (max_len,)
model = build_transformer_model(input_shape, english_vocab_size, sinhala_vocab_size)

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
# Train the model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=3, batch_size=64)

# Save the model
model.save('sinhala_english_transformer.h5')
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import pickle

# Load the model
model = load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/sinhala_english_transformer_new.h5')

# Load the tokenizers
with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/english_tokenizer_new.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    english_tokenizer = pickle.load(f)

with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/sinhala_tokenizer_new.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    sinhala_tokenizer = pickle.load(f)

# Set max_len to the value used during training
max_len = 55  # Adjust this to the value used during training

# Prepare new sentences for prediction (use the tokenizer and padding as before)
new_sentences = ["How does the Java Stream API help in processing collections?"]
new_sequences = english_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(new_sentences)
new_sequences = pad_sequences(new_sequences, maxlen=max_len, padding='post')

# Predict translation
predictions = model.predict(new_sequences)
translated_sequences = predictions.argmax(axis=-1)
translated_sentences = [' '.join(sinhala_tokenizer.index_word[idx] for idx in seq if idx > 0) for seq in translated_sequences]

print(translated_sentences)

I’ve tried adjusting the version locally to match the development environment but still encounter issues. I'm encountering an issue when loading a pre-trained TensorFlow model locally. The model works perfectly in my colab environment, but I get the following error when I try to load it on a my local environment.

looks like a version mismatch.  what version are you using in your local install?

tensorflow version is 2.17

you probably have different versions of keras, as keras is again an independent package.
